# Primefaces TabView bug using Google Chrome

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces TabView (showcase) seems to have a bug using Chrome (v.26.x.xx). 
In the first refresh all the tabs are rendered under the first tab and only clicking in one of the other tabs the state will be restored to the correct one.

Link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabview.jsf

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you observed this in any other browser?

Comment: With Firefox19, IE10 everything seems ok. The problem seems to appear only with Chrome. Observing with _Developer Tools_ no javascript error are been shown.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I'm facing exactly the same problem with version 46 of Chrome.